# sql select columns, count and sum of count

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this query that returns different columns and count of a column. it works perfectly fine.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT w.title, w.date ,COUNT(f.fid) AS f_count , GROUP_CONCAT(name)  
FROM Faculty f 
INNER JOIN Attend a ON a.fid = f.fid 
INNER JOIN Workshop w ON w.wid = a.wid 
WHERE f.did = 1 
GROUP BY w.title 
ORDER BY w.wid
```

in addition to these fields I also want to return the SUM of the f_count column. I have tried to use nested queries like this one:

```
SELECT title, date,f_count ,names,COUNT(f_count) AS total_f 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT w.title AS title, w.date AS date,COUNT(f.fid) AS f_count , GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS names  
FROM Faculty f 
INNER JOIN Attend a ON a.fid = f.fid 
INNER JOIN Workshop w ON w.wid = a.wid 
WHERE f.did = 1 
GROUP BY w.title 
ORDER BY w.wid) AS total_fac
```

the SUM would return the correct value but I only receive a single row from the inner query. 
I know that IN and ANY return multiple rows from subqueries but I don't see how I can use it in my case.

**My question is:**
How can I get all the rows + the SUM of COUNT ?

I have looked to other questions here but have not found what I was looking for.

Comment: You are `group by`ing by one column, so the sum of the count would be the number of all rows that would be returned if it wasnt there, am I correct?

Comment: the thing is I need to GROUP By to select distinct values. If I remove the GROUP BY the query will return redundant values

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns one row because the sum of your counts is actually the size of your resultset/inital `COUNT(*)` without the `GROUP BY` clause,

Also your date field is randomly selected because of the `GROUP BY`, that is a different issue.

To go about putting this value on all of your rows isn't necessary. You could run the same query again without the `GROUP BY`.

EDIT: I originally suggested that you bind the count to the second query but I have taken it out because I have changed my mind.

Comment: That I am told is the correct query.
I am a fan of transparency.
Sometimes.

Comment: The first line of the question.
"I have this query that returns different columns and count of a column. it works perfectly fine."

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. the thing is I need to GROUP By to select distinct values. If I remove the GROUP BY the query will return redundant values. However, I will try to work without the GROUP BY and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Octopi helped me figure out what was wrong with my query and how to get it right.

What I wanted was the "**number**" of DISTINCT faculty from a department who have attended any workshop. However, the previous query that I posted in the question was getting me the "**total sum**" of attended faculty in the workshops (not distinct).

So my approach was not correct to begin with. Therefore, I left the *first* query as is and created a *second* query to get me the number of DISTINCT faculty that I need As following:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS total_fac FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM Faculty f 
INNER JOIN Attend a ON f.fid = a.fid 
WHERE f.did = 1) AS total
```

this got me where I want. Discussing this question with you helped me get there

Thank you :)